# What is the best parity configuration to run a full archive node on raspberry pi?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, parity, nodes, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi to download the archived version of the blockchain with parity. I've started parity with

```
parity -d /home/xxx/data/Ethereum --pruning archive --public-node
```

However, the synchronisation is running at 0-5 blocks per second. At this rate, it won't finish for **1-2 years**.

Is there a setting that I can use to speed this up. For example, if I reduced the --max-peers to 10 would it speed up the synchronisation? Or is this an unachievable feat for a Pi?

Comment: I don't know how you can speed it up on a Raspberry Pi, but is it feasible in your situation to sync on another machine and then move the synced chain to the Pi?

Comment: @lungj yes, it is possible for me to sync elsewhere but I have a feeling an archive sync will take over a day - longer than i'm willing to leave my desktop on for. I had some feedback from the parity channel that compiling locally might resolve the issue. I'll update with the result when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely to take 10-20 years on a Raspberry Pi given the current Ethereum blockchain utilization with more than 400k transactions per day.

Even on commodity hardware it's taking weeks to complete an archive sync due to the spam blocks in autumn 2016.

The most obvious way to get this done is attaching the external drive which is hopefully an SSD with at least 500 GB to some fast machine, sync up in archive mode and once finished, mount it on your Raspberry Pi and attach it with `--db-path`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm at 2.2M blocks and syncing on a 1TB external so it will be no problem for me to switch this to my desktop if it takes too long. FYI - building parity from source has sped it up by quite a bit.

Comment: Good to know...